# '06 Ford Focus Central Locking Failure

Tags: electrical, ford, focus, locks

The central locking in my '06 Ford Focus has stopped working. I can put the key into the door and lock and unlock the car, but I can't use the fob on the key.

#### What I tried:

1. I tried to put a new battery in the key.

   - A new battery didn't solve the issue.
2. I then tried reprogramming the key.

   - I used the method of putting the key in and turning it from position 0 to 2 four times and then pressing a key. This seemed to tell me that the key is working as it bleeped when I pressed the key fob. It still doesn't let me lock and unlock the car though.
3. I looked for the mysterious fuse 63.

   - On the back of my fuse board, there are no fuses and it doesn't look like the fuse boards in the video so gave up.
4. My manual said to look on the passenger-side fuse board for the central locking relay. It should be fuse 120.

   - My fuses only go up to about 80 so I gave up on that.
5. I found a [video online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fh6a895PeA) which does show my fuse board. If you skip to 2:50 it lists fuses 55 and 77 as relating to the central locking.

   - Both fuses seemed fine.

#### Can anyone recommend anything else I can try?

Comment: Do you have a second key? Did you try it?

Comment: Also, what year is the car?

Comment: @Paulster2 Second key doesnt work :(

Comment: @rana Its a 2006

Answer (score 2):

Just unplug your battery for 5 minutes and connect it back. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the computer 'forgot' the key. If reprogramming did not help,try registering the key with a dealer scan tool.